# Having Trouble Using A Ternary Statement

Tags: c++, ternary

I'm making a binary tree and this is my insert function; it works perfectly:

```
if(newData < data){
    if(left) left->insert(newData);
    else left = new Node(newData);
}else{
    if(right) right->insert(newData);
    else right = new Node(newData);
}
```

I wanted to transform this into this:

```
if(newData < data)
    left ? left->insert(newData) : left = new Node(newData);
else
    right = right ? right : new Node(newData);
```

However, I'm getting this error:
Left operand to ? is void, but right operand is of type 'Node *'

I understand this is because there's something to do with having the ternary statement be the same on both sides, but I was wondering if anyone knew a possible solution for this short of just using an if/else statement so I can learn the limitations behind the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. The original code is more readable. Also, the transformed version doesn't do the same thing as the original code.

Comment: Use `(<expression>)` especially when expression performs assignment

Comment: Easy peasy, just do `((newData < data) ? left : right) = (newData < data) ? (left ? ((void)left->insert(newData), left) : new Node(newData)) : (right ? ((void)right->insert(newData), right) : new Node(newData));` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Not only more readable, but more maintainable also.

Comment: Not quiet sure how Stack Over Flow works, so forgive me if this is the wrong place to put this or reply to you guys, but I totally understand that this is impractical code. With that being said, I still wanted to see if I could do it for fun, and when I couldn't, I really want to see why that was the case.

Comment: Eljay I love you. While this kind of coding is generally bad practice, what you pointed out is something that I was trying to do myself: that beginning part, you used a ternary statement to choose what was going to be assigned. Thank you!

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm, what about what Eljay did? It works! Again, I know the former is what I should submit, this is just purely to find out if I could do something rather than should I keep it

Answer (score 1):

The [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) is an expression.

It is not an `if else` statement.

It returns a result - at runtime, so its type has to be determined during compilation.

It can only be one type at a time, so in effect both branches have to return a result of the same type

In your branches, the types of the expressions are different. This is the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator ? is not just a shorthand for if, but requires three expressions:
`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

If the condition evaluates to true, the whole constuct evaluates to `exprIfTrue`, if false to `exprIfFalse`. In contrast to `if` it can be used in an assignment, hence the two expressions have to have a type that conforms to the variable the result is assigned to. `?` can better be compared to the `if` in functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that helped so incredibly quickly! To all of you who mentioned the readability of the new code as opposed to the original, I totally understand that I should keep it as it is in the beginning. Thanks to everyone posting about the nature of the statement!

For anyone ends up wondering what the solution was, for fun, Eljay nailed it:

```
((newData < data) ? left : right) =
      (newData < data) ? (left ? (( void )left->insert(newData), left)
                               : new Node(newData))
                       : (right ? (( void )right->insert(newData), right)
                                : new Node(newData));
```

Thank you all so much! I'm extremely impressed by how awesome the StackOverflow community is!